# Minikube/Kubernetes mountPath is not accessible

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am running minikube/Kubernetes and am having difficulty accessing a volume from a volumeMount in a deployment.

I can confirm that when the microservice starts up, it is not able to access the /config directory (ie. the "mountPath" in the "volumeMounts").  I have verified that the hostPath/path is valid.

I have experimented with a number of techniques and have also validated that the deployment files is correct.  I have also tried using quotes/double-quotes/no-quotes around the path specifications, but this does not address the issue.

Note that I am using a "hostPath" for simple testing purposes, however, this is the scenario that I nevertheless need to address.

My minikube configuration is illustrated below:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"08e099554f3c31f6e6f07b448ab3ed78d0520507", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-01-12T07:30:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"08e099554f3c31f6e6f07b448ab3ed78d0520507", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"1970-01-01T00:00:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I am running minikube on MacOS/Sierra version 10.12.3 (16D32).

My deployment file (deployment.yaml):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: atmp1000-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: atmp1000
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: atmp1000
        image: atmp1000
        ports:
        - containerPort: 7010
        volumeMounts:
          - name: atmp1000-volume
            mountPath: '/config'
      volumes:
      - name: atmp1000-volume
        hostPath:
          path: '/Users/<username>/<some-path>/config'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of completeness, below is the solution that I found... I got the hostPath and mounts working on minikube (on Mac) which took a few steps but required several "minikube delete" commands to get the most current version and reset the environment.  Below are some additional notes about how to get this functioning:

- I had to use the xhyve driver to make it all work properly -- it probably works using other drivers but I did not try them.
- I found that minikube mounts host paths at "/User" which means the "volumes/hostPath/path" should start at "/User"
- I found a variety of ways that this worked including using claims but the files in the original question now reflect a correct and simple configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Host mounting directories is not supported by minikube yet. Please check https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2

Internally minikube uses a virtual machine to host Kubernetes. If you specify `hostPath` in a POD spec, Kubernetes will host mount the specified directory inside the VM and not the directory on your actual host.

If you really need to access something on your host machine, you have to use NFS or any other network based volume type.

Comment: OK.  I can try nfs, however, minikube documentation specifically states that hostPath can be used for minikube.. see https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) and see: http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/07/minikube-easily-run-kubernetes-locally.html).  I am not sure if it make any difference but I amd using the xhyve hypervisor on Mac instead of using the VirtualBox version.

Comment: From the first link you mentioned: "Minikube supports PersistentVolumes of type hostPath. These PersistentVolumes are mapped to a directory inside the minikube VM."

Please note the last sentence. It says that the host mount is based on the directory INSIDE the VM.

Comment: Quick questions regarding hostPath as I cant find it specifically discussed in the documentation: if I wanted to access host files from inside the minikube VM and in pods, where on the host is the minikube root directory that I should place files into such that they can be visible in the mounthPath (I realize this is not a best practice, but am trying to solve a particular problem)?

Comment: Ahh sorry, I just re-read the minikube readme. In [mounted-host-folders](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube#mounted-host-folders), I see that /Users is actually shared between the VM and the host, so your initial Deployment should actually work as expected. Which error do you get? It may also be a permission problem.

Comment: I am trying to access a config file that exists in a specific host directory, and accessing it from the pod gets an error saying the file does not exists.  I believe that this occurs because I am incorrectly mounting the directory.  But if I understand your comment that /Users is already mounted (I see a share in /etc/exports) then the root directory in the pod is mapped to the share.  If this is the case, then maybe I need relative paths from the mount point (/Users)?  thoughts?